# Mentoring to help new users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have not found a question about this so I would like to propose a mentoring System to help newcomers (like myself). There are documentations, there are Q&A and yes, all those should be read. But they don't have all the answers that new users might need and they can be unclear specially assuming that this is a multicultural environment. So a mentoring System would be appreciated in which a better experienced user can take newcomers as a mentor and establish a communication channel to it. Would be better if the mentor would be from the same country/region as the mentored. That may also increase the quality of questions and answers all across the community specially if the mentor get automatically notified when the mentored has questions and answers with a high number of down votes.

Comment: Welcome! Trying to serve you in the function you propose: a down-vote on a feature request of meta only means that somebody does not consider this as a good feature. You should thus not be taken aback by it. Perhaps you could say what type of information or advice you would hope to receive.

Comment: Thanks @quid. I do understand that down-voting is not an attack. I didn't understand what you mean by "Perhaps you could say what type of information or advice you would hope to receive.". If you are talking about what kind of discussion I expect for this question specifically then it would be a tool to make this community/environment more friendly for new users. As I said this is a multicultural environment and sometimes a question can be perfectly clear for a culture but unclear for another.

Comment: I meant mainly what type of information you find lacking or not easy enough to find.

Comment: That makes things clear, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few problems with this

- Anyone can make an account in 10 seconds, we don't have enough experienced users to mentor everyone and becoming a "mentor" requires some dedication not too many will volunteer to do so
- Who is "experienced" anyways?
- Users interested in "mentoring" will look for help and find it anyways, I presume (do you have any question about the site whose answer you couldn't find in the help center or meta?)

Also I believe there are enough alternatives

- You can always drop in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) if you have specific questions another user can help you with.
- If you have issues with site policy, you can ask a meta question or contact mods in the [Math Mods' Office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office)
- Some users (including me) will add comprehensive "introductory comments" to new users' question if something is wrong with them. Thus they will get pointed to the correct sources if they make mistakes and won't be bothered if they don't.

It seems that you have experienced difficulties with your *first* question asked. This is absolutely not a huge issue. You can always improve and I've taken the time to add some comments about what is wrong with the post's form that got it closed. Don't let this (relatively small) negative feedback keep you from becoming an active member on Math.SE :)

Comment: AlexR thanks for your answer. Yes, there are many users but the idea is not to have every single one being mentored. 

It would requires that both the new user request this kind of help and another user agree to do so.

You are way more experienced than me. (member for 1 and a half year versus a few days)

Specific help about how to improve questions and answers are not the goal of help center or meta from my point of view.

about the chat: "You must have 20 reputation" it is supposed to be easy to achieve but if the user fails to have good questions he might be left out without understanding.

Comment: @Pfeiffer Still I don't see a _particual_ use case. I've looked at your question and seen that unfortunately noone told you why it was put on hold. If you want to know about that (_why_ was my question put on hold), you should still be able to comment on the question and ask someone and maybe edit the question to make it meet the requirements. Note that you only have _one shot_ at improving the question wich causes it to pass reopen-review, so make sure the edit is worth it.

Comment: I appreciate your participation on both here and that question of mine.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that your third point goes both ways - users interested in *providing* help already can to whatever extent they are willing.

Comment: @Meelo I agree with you, it's kind of what I mean with the 3rd bullet in the second listing though ;)